# No Sound after Midi-recording?

Tags: sound, midi

What I did:

1. I turned QSynth on,
2. I turned JACK on,
3. I turned both off,

I wanted to get an Output from my E-Piano.
Instead I don't get any Sounds out of my System (Ubuntu 14.04) anymore.
How do I fix that?

Comment: It was really clear before, but OK, now I structurized it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **PulseAudio Volume Control** application to fix this? You can find it in Ubuntu Software Center.

Something went wrong with your audio configuration probably. PulseAudio Volume Control is very powerful and I think you should be able to fix it. It will help in many other situations as well.